# Trying to create Binomial tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would love to have a nice tikz-version of this drawing of a binomial tree.
[image]

and my lines are not that nice, can anybody help me

So far I've made the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=2em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{end} = [text width=3em, text centered]
%\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill=red!30,rounded corners]



% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped, edge from parent]
\node[bag] {$S_{0}$} % First bag
child{node[bag] {$S_{0}d$} % Step 1 down
   child{node[bag]{$S_{0}d^{2}$} % step 2 down
       child{node[end]{$S_{0}d^{3}$}} % step 3 down
       child{node[end] {}} % step 3 up
       }
   child{node[bag] {} % step 2 up
       child{node[end]{}} %step 3 down
       child{node[end] {}} %step 3 up
           }
  }
   child {node[bag] {$S_{0}u$} % step 1 up
      child{node[bag]{$S_{0}ud$}
          child{node[end]{$S_{0}ud^{2}$}} % step 3 down
          child{node[end]{}} % step 3 up
          } % step 2 down
        child{node[bag ]{$S_{0}u^{2}$} % step 2 up
           child{node[end]{$S_{0}u^{2}d$}} % step 3 down
           child{node[end]{$S_{0}u^{3}$}} % step 3 up
       }
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Tikz and macros to very efficiently draw recombining binomial trees when taking notes during class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237483/how-to-use-tikz-and-macros-to-very-efficiently-draw-recombining-binomial-trees-w)

Comment: Welcome to this site! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227414/draw-5-period-binomial-tree will certainly answer your question.  As a new user it's also very convenient to check site:tex.stackexchange.com <search term(s)> via google. You'll find plenty of ressource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
  edge from parent/.style={draw,
    edge from parent path={
      (\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)
    }
  }
```

in the option list of `tikzpicture`.
[image]

Comment: Thank you :) it worked !!!

Comment: @GHG If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark on its left.